# Difference between interpreting "for" loop in php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, for-loop

sorry for my bad english.

I've got such a question: why the first code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { position: relative; }
      table { position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px; }
      div { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black; margin: auto auto; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var j = i + '';
        $("#menu_div_" + j).mouseover(function(){
          $("#menu_div_" + j).clearQueue();
          $("#menu_div_" + j).stop();
          $("#menu_div_" + j).animate({
            width: 150,
            height: 150
          }, 600
          );
        });
        $("#menu_div_" + j).mouseout(function(){
          $("#menu_div_" + j).clearQueue();
          $("#menu_div_" + j).stop();
          $("#menu_div_" + j).animate({
            width: 100,
            height: 100
          }, 600
          );
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="menu">
<? for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
      <tr>
<?   for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) { ?>
        <td>
          <div id="menu_div_<? echo ($i * 10) + $j; ?>">
          </div>
        </td>
<?   } ?>
      </tr>
<? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

doesn't work exactly the same like in this code ("for" loop is written in php):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { position: relative; }
      table { position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px; }
      div { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black; margin: auto auto; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) { ?>
        $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).mouseover(function(){
          $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).clearQueue();
          $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).stop();
          $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).animate({
            width: 150,
            height: 150
          }, 600
          );
        });
        $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).mouseout(function(){
          $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).clearQueue();
          $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).stop();
          $("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>).animate({
            width: 100,
            height: 100
          }, 600
          );
        });
<?php } ?>
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="menu">
    <? for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
      <tr>
    <?   for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) { ?>
        <td>
          <div id="menu_div_<? echo ($i * 10) + $j; ?>">
          </div>
        </td>
    <?   } ?>
      </tr>
    <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Quick explanation:

In the first one, "events" from all "div" tags result in changing the size of the last element (I don't know why). In the second - "event" from each "div" results in changing size of the same "div" (what, in my opinion, should also happen in the first code too).

How can I correct first code to make it work like the second one?

Comment: Have you compared the static js code to the dinamically generated one by PHP?

Comment: You should declare `var i;` before the for loop.  Also, `var j = i + '';` is not needed `$("#menu_div_" + i)` will work fine.

Comment: I don't exactly know what do you meen saying "compared", but I think - yes. Both codes should make the same think. (I forgot to add that i'm programming in javascript only from a week, so may comparation could be wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` doesn't equal what you think it will. It will **ALWAYS** come back with 99.  This is due to the defining anonymous functions within a loop.

Luckily, with a little jQuery magic, this is easily fixed.  Rather than trying to reference each element directly, `$('#menu_div_'+j)`, just use `$(this)`.  Inside jQuery event handlers, `this` is automatically set the to element/target of the event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var j = i + '';
    $("#menu_div_" + j).mouseover(function(){
      $(this).clearQueue();
      $(this).stop();
      $(this).animate({
        width: 150,
        height: 150
      }, 600
      );
    });
    $("#menu_div_" + j).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).clearQueue();
      $(this).stop();
      $(this).animate({
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      }, 600
      );
    });
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AXgwF/)

Answer (score 3):

Mark all of the animating menu divs with the same class and do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.animating_menu_div_class')
    .mouseover(function(){
      $(this).clearQueue()
         .stop()
         .animate({
            width: 150,
            height: 150
            }, 600);
     });
    .mouseout(function(){
      $(this).clearQueue()
         .stop()
         .animate({
            width: 100,
            height: 100
            }, 600);
     });
  }
});
```

Here, I redid the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dtanders/fAYhA/

Comment: unfortunately i've tried it in opera and firefox and it doesn't work.

Comment: I originally pasted bad code - sorry about that.  The current code should be fine.

Comment: +1 for the use of `this` inside the event handlers and being first.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, this *should* result in the same code.<sup>1</sup>

The first example does it with JavaScript (client-side) and the second does it with PHP (server-side).

Likely your issue is with PHP output, as it differs from JavaScript.

For example, in all instances change:

```
$("#menu_div_" + <?php echo $i; ?>)
```

To:

```
$("#menu_div_<?php echo $i; ?>")
```

<sup>1</sup> *Although you can get into the details of performance, separation, and other web development wormholes.*

Comment: But second one works in the way i like. The first one does strange thinks.

Comment: @Tomasz Then use the first :)

Comment: @Tomasz The first one does strange things because it outputs `$("#menu_div_"1)` instead of `$("#menu_div_1")`. Since the number is not part of the string in the first, jQuery thinks the id is `#menu_div_` instead of `#menu_div_1`

Comment: The issue is with defining anonymous functions within a loop. Inside the event handlers, `j == 99`. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AXgwF/).

Comment: @Jason McCreary - :p I just wanted to learn sth. about javascript

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Thanks -  I haven't noticed it.

Comment: @Tomasz, upon second glance your issue with the first is pointed out by **circusbred**. For the solution use `$(this)` inside of your event handlers. See **dtanders**.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the first one doesn't work like the second is that, in Javascript, you're forming a closure around the variable `j` in your event handlers, and closures aren't evaluated immediately. Thus, you keep modifying `j` every iteration, but it isn't evaluated until the events are triggered, so the evaluated value is the value set in the last iteration.